# How can I wait until data comes in when reading data over Serial Port? QT C++

Tags: c++, qt

I need to read ID data through Serial Port. When I send the ID read command with the leather port, the ID data comes to me a little late. Therefore, when I try to split the data and display it on the screen, it comes up blank and the application closes itself. How can I wait until the data comes in?

```
void productDetail::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QSerialPortInfo info;
        QList<QSerialPortInfo> infoList = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();

           foreach(info, infoList) QTextStream(stdout) << info.portName();
        QString curport = info.portName();


   serial.begin(curport, 9600, 8, 0, 1, 0, false);

   if(serial.isOpen()){
       qDebug()<<"serial open";
       QString sendWC= "WR+1121"; //Read ID command
       serial.send(sendWC);
       QString serialID = serial.getString();

        serialID = serialID.trimmed();
         QStringList buffer_split = serialID.split(",");

             ui->IDlabel->setText(buffer_split[2]; //when I write this program closes

             }
   }

}
```

> error: ASSERT failure in QList::operator[]: "index out of range",

Comment: I'm certain there's a signal being emitted when something arrives on the serial port. You should connect to that signal and handle it like any other Qt signal.

Comment: Also remember that serial communication is streaming and byte-wise. There's no guarantee that a single "read" call will return a full message. Or that it will only receive a single message. You need to be able to handle partial, or more than one (including one and a partial) messages.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There is a signal on the other page. Do I need to create a new signal for this page?

Comment: Don't ready anything from IO device in pushbutton callback, because most likely you will freeze your GUI. Instead inside `on_pushButton_clicked` only write the command. Connect to https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qiodevice.html#readyRead and do something with the return message when it is available.

Answer (score 0):

Qt's **QIODevice** provides a signal `readyRead` (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead)  which is emitted once every time new data is available for reading from the device.

In the `productDetail` class constructor, connect serial port `readyRead` signal to a slot.

```cpp
connect(serial, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, &productDetail::readData);
```

Define `readData` method as follows:

```cpp
void productDetail::readData()
{
    const QByteArray data = m_serial->readAll();
}
```

For serial communication there is no guarantee that you will receive entire message data in a single read. I prefer to store the received data in a circular buffer and process the circular buffer in a separate slot.